# News Page on a Portfolio?

Tags: website-design, ux-field, portfolio

I have a question regarding to see if putting a News (or recent news) page on a portfolio website is a good UX practice.

I see news pages on almost every single corporate websites, but not often on portfolios of individuals (creators, directors, artists, etc).

I know this topic might be somewhat subjective but I would appreciate any insights.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! You already guessed that your question might be subjective - we call that opinion-based and rule out such questions, as they don't give anyone more insights into UX. Maybe if you tell us (a) what your users are, (b) what your site offers to them, (c) which news you plan to add and why they are interesting to the users - maybe then we can discuss your use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, from my side of view there a lot of important points of benefits for every one of us to include a blog page or section on a portfolio website.

- Blogs show more of your personality and are often less polished and more authentic.
- You can connect with some other designers/developers and general with like-minded individuals.
- You can make your followers be a part of your journey and share with them your experience, your thoughts.
- You can attract clients.

In this journey, you can learn and you will show the authentic version of yourself.
Visitors engage with blogs. The blog visitors can leave their comments in your entries, share your blog posts and return for your next blog posts. Simply, they follow you.

In the end, I believe that if you are suitable for showing your personality, then it is a great way to make your portfolio stand out because the portfolio of a UX designer is not to show some shoots but as a UX designer you should write down your thoughts and show about how you solve the problem. Blogs are content driven and portfolios are design-driven.

Comment: You make good points. May I kindly suggest using the word "authentic" instead of "uncouth", as the latter has a negative connotation?

Comment: Thanks @StacyH. Yes, of course, I change the content and I apply your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

A portfolio blog is a great place to list accomplishments that lie outside your body of work, such as speaking engagements and industry awards. You could make it timely, such as "I will be speaking at DesignCon in September on UX Research, if you are there, let's meet!"

As with everything, keep the audience in mind, and write for them.